# Any third party api's for Image Filtering

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, ios4, filtering

As I know IOS 4 doesn't support core Image, is there any third party api's or frameworks that support image filtering.

I thank you guys for all your valuable answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenCV http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/.
And here http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/overview/ you can download a Xcode Project that is set up to use OpenCV

Comment: Opencv can't be used for image Filtering.

Comment: Maybe we speak about different things but with opencv you can apply filters to your images. Here is an overiew of available filters. http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/image_filtering.html

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, I will try it